# Laravel 5 form select ID attribute not being added

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a Laravel form attribute as shown below:

```php
{!! 
Form::select('industry', $industries,  array('class' =>
            'form-control', 'style'=>' resize:vertical; ',
            'id' => 'industryId')) 
!!}
```

The problem is I'm unable to get id 'indusrtyId'.
The HTML output is:

```html
<select name="industry"> 
   <option value="1">Accounting</option>
   <option value="2">Airlines/Aviation</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add `null` as third parameter:

```
{!! Form::select('industry', $industries, null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'style'=>' resize:vertical; ', 'id' => 'industryId')) !!}
```

Third parameter is used to set `selected` element. Array with HTML parameters should be fourth parameter in `Form::select` clause.

Comment: thnx man its working now, official documentation site for help 
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html